# How to constrain a set of columns to all be NULL or all be NOT NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

Lets say I have a table like so,

```
id | first name | middle name | last name
```

Now, the `name` columns can be `NULL`, but if any of the three, for example, `first name` is `NOT NULL`, then all three must be `NOT NULL`.

How can I enforce this in Oracle?

Comment: You might have to use a trigger for that and write the check yourself, at least have it as plan B if you don't get a better answer from someone that know more about Oracle

Comment: Whilst you can write a check constraint for this, you might want to consider a different strategy - isolate these "must all have the same null-ness" columns into a *separate* table that doesn't allow nulls. Then your constraint is enforced by the *presence* or *absence* of a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a check constraint with the logics you need.
For example:

```
alter table yourTable
  add constraint check_not_null check
    (   
        first_name  is not null and
        middle_name is not null and
        last_name   is not null
      OR
        first_name  is null and
        middle_name is null and
        last_name   is null
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Say,

```
alter table your_table 
  add constraint set_of_column_chk
  check (nvl2(first_name, 1, 0) + nvl2(middle_name, 1, 0) + nvl2(last_name, 1, 0) in (0, 3));
```